# How To Get Per Face Images Without Explicit UV Image

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to get the image to repeat on each face it is assigned to instead of stretching across all of the faces without going in a pasting the same image in the image texture for every button. The button panel is its own object, each top is assigned the same material, and the sides of the buttons are assigned another material.

I know I can stack the button top UVs on top of each other, but I don't want to generate separate maps for the top and side. This seems like it should be an easy thing to do in nodes or a simple setting in the material I'm missing.
[image: Pic]

[image: Pic]

Comment: You could select all these faces and press U > Reset, they will overlap

Comment: Yeah sure. That does work but it also squares the side UVs. I suppose this is the simplest thing to do and I'll just go forward with that although getting the side UV's to be conformal and overlapping would be another problem.

Comment: Weren't your buttons an array, anyway? That's one unwrap  for the array-element (default looks fine, here) and then apply, if necessary?

Comment: I mean I'm dealing with the same problem with another piece of my model. Unless I split off into separate objects or create separate UVs it won't work. I'd like to just be able to scale the image within the separate faces.